# Schedule UILocalNotification based on changes to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uilocalnotification, today-extension

I'm making a simple app with a Today Widget extension that logs events.

The user can tap a button in the app or the related Today Widget to log an event. These events are saved with Core Data any time the button is pressed either place.

Whenever a new event is logged in the app, I run a function called `updateLocalNotificationsFromCoreData()`. It handles the setup of UILocalNotifications based on the most recent event in Core Data after clearing the appropriate existing notifications.

However, when a new event is logged from the Today Widget, I can't use this function because I need to register the Local Notification with `UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification()`, and UIApplication is not available in the Today Widget extension.

I realize I'll probably need do something unconventional or hacky to get this working, so I'm trying to evaluate possible approaches and come up with a relatively robust solution.

**Basically, I want to find a way I can call my 
`updateLocalNotificationsFromCoreData()` function right away any time a new event is logged.**

If I can't do it every time an event is logged, an alternative would be to trigger the `updateLocalNotificationsFromCoreData()` function periodically (somewhat frequently) another way. Here are some solutions I was thinking about using, but I don't like any of them:

### Do it in AppDelegate when the app is launched (or another state change)

One approach I'm thinking about is running my `updateLocalNotificationsFromCoreData()`function in AppDelegate somewhere, like `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

The downside is that it would require the user to open the app periodically. If the user didn't open it much the notification behavior would be inconsistent. I'd prefer a solution where a user could interact with only the Today Widget and reliably get Local Notifications without ever opening the app.

### Sync the events to a server and use Push Notifications

I've thought about syncing the data in Core Data to a server, then setting up Push Notifications to the user's phone based on that.

I don't like this, because I want the user to still be able to get notifications without an Internet connection. It also introduces a lot of extra overhead of syncing the data with a server.

### Ping a server, and send a content-available Push Notification

When someone logs an event with the widget, I could ping a server. That server could send back a silent content-available push notification to trigger the app to run `updateLocalNotificationsFromCoreData()` in the background.

I found a similar question ([Scheduling local notification from within a Today extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689629/scheduling-local-notification-from-within-a-today-extension)) where one answer proposes a similar solution. Unlike the previous solution, an Internet connection is not needed to *receive* the notifications, but an Internet connection would be required to make sure the notifications are up to date when a new event is logged.

### Background fetch

I thought about using Background Fetch to fetch something arbitrary from a server, then run the `updateLocalNotificationsFromCoreData()`. This would be a way to trigger the update in the background, although it seems silly to fetch data if that data isn't being used, and seems like something for which an app could be rejected. There also seems to be a risk of the system not calling the background update regularly if the user doesn't open the app much and mostly uses the Today Widget.

### Use background location updates

This seems like the dumbest approach, but I thought I would mention it anyway since I thought about it. I could use one of the low accuracy background location update modes to trigger `updateLocalNotificationsFromCoreData()`.

It would require the user to allow location in the background, which would be hard to explain. And, it would require the user to at least move around a few blocks to trigger the function, which could provide an inconsistent user experience. Also, it would increase power consumption of the app for a silly reason.

---

I'd really appreciate fresh ideas about how I might be able to **reliably schedule local notifications when Core Data changes on a device that doesn't have an Internet connection**!

Or, if that doesn't seem possible, I'd appreciated feedback on which approach seems to make the most sense.

---

**EDIT:** I came up with a new solution. It's not ideal, but I think it's better than these other approaches I was considering. When someone taps the button to log the event, I launch the full app. It's annoying because I have all the data I need at that point to give the user feedback and log the event within the Today Widget without launching the app, but by launching the app I have the opportunity to check and schedule local notifications.

Also, in iOS 9 the annoyance on the user is slightly minimized because the system-wide "back" button will appear and let the user go back to the previous app easily once my app has launched from the Today Widget.

In the future I may try a solution where one of the server-based approaches above is used when an Internet connection is available, and I would then fall back to this system of opening the app only when the network connection is not available and I need to schedule the local notifications within the app.