# Showing an alert in Today Extension (widget) using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I have a Today Extension and I have a textfield and button and what I want to do is `if textfield.hasText == true` do something and `if textfield.hasText == false` then i want to show an alert within the widget

Comment: Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850263/7469518) out, it might be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Keyboard Entry** is not allowed in **iOS Extensions**, so have a `UITextField` in **Today Widget** doesn't make any sense.

> Because user interaction with Today widgets is quick and limited, you
>   should design a simple, streamlined UI that highlights the information
>   users are interested in. In general, it’s a good idea to limit the
>   number of interactive items in a widget. In particular, note that iOS
>   widgets don’t support keyboard entry.